# append data to exisiting dataframe using a function in python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
id    user_id    name       city            email
 1       1       John       Mexico City     john@example.com
 2       2       Conor      NY              conor@example.com
 3       3       Albert     Florida city    albert@example.com
 4       4       James      Florida city    james@example.com
```

Also I have a mysql table `user_data`:

```
id    email1              email2                  status
1    john@example.com                            active
2                      conor@example.com         active
3                      albert@example.com        delete
4    james@example.com                           active
```

I have to append the data of the `status` column to the dataframe based on an sql query

```
def fetchStatus(con, user_id, email):
    sql = """select status from user_data where id = %s and ( email1 = '%s' or email2 = '%s' )"""%(user_id, email, email)
    status_data = pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

`status_data` contains the status of the particular `user_id` and `email` and should append the status to dataframe

Desired result

```
id    user_id    name       city            email                  status
 1       1       John       Mexico City     john@example.com       active
 2       2       Conor      NY              conor@example.com      active
 3       3       Albert     Florida city    albert@example.com     delete
 4       4       James      Florida city    james@example.com      active
```

Method I used before:

I've extracted the table as dataframe using pandas and joining the two dataframes using `user_id`

But now I want to use the function way. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `join` or `merge` native pandas functions will do the trick.

I think you'll just have to edit the SQL query so that you get the Id as well as the status.

```py
def fetchStatus(con, user_id, email):
    sql = """select id, status from user_data where id = %s and ( email1 = '%s' or email2 = '%s' )"""%(user_id, email, email)
    status_data = pd.read_sql(sql, con)

df_merged = sample_df.set_index('user_id').join(status_data.set_index('id'))
```

Comment: How do I call this function for every row in the dataframe?